# node js problem, how to run js file in local server using vs code

Tags: node.js

what to do how run node js in my vs code

solve the problem
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\express\3.1+Express+Server\index.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Comment: Show us some code and how you're trying to run it. We don't have a magic crystal ball to guess.

Comment: Add your code to the question after removing the confidential data. We can't find the issue without the code.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file "index.js" exist in the /3.1+Express+Server/ folder?